# Cannot merge new index 69355 into a non-jumbo instruction with IONIC and INTERCOM

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, intercom

I'm building an iOS/Android app using IONIC and since i added the intercom cordova plugin ( ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-intercom ) i can't build my app with this error :

> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index
>   69355 into a non-jumbo instruction

What should I do to fix and be able to build again ?

Answer (score 0):

**Source of the problem :**

It happens when the amount of strings (methods, members, etc) in a single dex file is to high. A dex file is the result of the compilation of your app. It's then turned into it's compressed version : the apk. Most of the time it's related to using third parties libraries like Google Analytics, Intercom ...

**Solution :**

To enable multidex on IONIC you just have to install the related cordova plugin :

> ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-multidex --save

After runing this command, the pluggin will be installed and you will be able to build your app.